# Giving users no-access permissions

Tags: permissions

I have a site that has a subsite.  Users need permissions to the subsite but cannot be allowed to see the main site at all (they should get a access denied).

Generally how I do it is, I break permissions inheritance for the subsite, then create a new group for that subsite with the required permissions.  Then for the main site, I place the users in whatever group I need.  The problem is, as far as I know, there is no way to specify a group with "no access".

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a reason to specify no access, just don't add the users to a group ;)

SharePoint will assume the highest level of permission granted to the user, so if they're in two groups, the higher level of permission will reign. If they're in no groups, then no access.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Adding a group specific to the subsite gives them permissions to that subsite but still places them in a group visible in the "main" site, but technically this group is specific to the subsite only.  That was what was throwing me off.  Removing that user from any other groups on the main-site level fixed the problem.I learned something new!Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad i could help, check out my blog post which may help clarify some more http://davidlozzi.com/2011/08/30/simplifying-sharepoint-user-management/